# To get string from selected text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dropdown

I am using dropdown list to get the selected text value 
here is my code

```
var priceValue = $("#ddlprice option:selected").text();
```

and i am getting value like **Basic Cotton Ultra ($20.05)**

I just want **Basic Cotton Ultra** from the value 
so how can i extract this.

Comment: Assuming you want to split before the `(` then just use `split(' (')[0]`. This may be rather brittle though, so it would depend on the actual HTML, which you haven't shown.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Regular expression to remove all the brackets and tex inside like  bellow snippet :

```js
var result = "Basic Cotton Ultra ($20.05)".replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
alert(result);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great answer @bRIMOs

Comment: Thnx Billy :D hope u're doing well

Answer (score 1):

just split it before '(' and you will get the output..

```
var pricevalue = "Basic Cotton Ultra ($20.05)";
pricevalue = pricevalue.split('(')[0].trim();
//output will be "Basic Cotton Ultr
```